Do common people know about Mahābhāratam?
Was Mahabharata popular before the TV series by Mr BR Chopra?
Like , did grandparents talk about the Mahābhārata?

Several Telugu movies were based on Mahabharata/Ramayana themes in 1950s, 60s. So I guess at least in AP/Telangana, common people knew about Mahabharata.
